# Confused about how to add columns to jtable programmatically

Tags: java, jtable

I have created a jtable and a class that extends AbstractTableModel. Actually I am not sure If I did correct so far. The problem is that I can't add any columns to my jtable. I am getting null pointer in the main method. This is what I have tried so far. Can you please take a look What is missing and wrong.

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5)) ;
JTable table;
public CheckBoxes(){

    table=new JTable(new TableModels());
    TableColumnModel columnModel = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
        columnModel.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(100);
    }
    panel.add(table);
    this.add(panel);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CheckBoxes().setVisible(true);
}
class TableModels extends AbstractTableModel{
    String[] colName=new String[]{"Name","Url"};
    int[][]data=new int[10][2];
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return colName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data[row][col];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = null;
```

to

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
```

Comment: Thank you Danny  and a few minutes later I will accept your answer..One more thing Is everyting correct in my TableModels  class

Comment: Two things: 1) add the following method: `public String getColumnName(int col) { return colName[col]; }` to display the column name in the table header, and add the `JTable` to a `JScrollPane` and add the `JScrollPane` (instead of the `JTable`) to the `panel` so that the table header is displayed.